# How to model diffusion through a membrane?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, discontinuity, heat-equation, mass-transport

This is a follow-up on [How to handle discontinuity in diffusion coefficient?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/218981/12)

Consider diffusion of $u(t,x)$ on the domain $x \in [0,2]$ with some simple boundary conditions such as $u(0) = 2, u(2) = 1$.

Our domain is split into two parts: $[0,1)$ on the left and $(1,2]$ on the right, with different diffusion coefficients, e.g. $D^\text{left} = 1, D^\text{right} = 3$.

The diffusion equation is:
$$
\partial_t u = \partial_x (D \partial_x u)
$$

**So far, this is the summary of the linked question.**

---

This time we also have a membrane at $x=1$, imposing the following condition on the fluxes at $x=1$:
$$
D^\text{left} \partial_x u^\text{left} = 
D^\text{right} \partial_x u^\text{right} = 
d^\text{membrane} (u^\text{right} - u^\text{left})
$$

What is the cleanest way to model this with `NDSolve`? Is there a way to preserve the sharp conditions at $x=1$? Perhaps one approximation that could be used is to consider a membrane of finite thickness, having a very high diffusion coefficient of its own. However, this is really a hack. Is it possible to solve the equation on the two half-domains "separately" and couple the boundary conditions at $x=1$?

Comment: I don't think this can be solved only with `NDSolve`. Using my `pdetoode` to discretize should be relatively straightforward though. Is an answer with `pdetoode` desired?

Comment: @xzczd Yes please.

Comment: @Szabolcs You did not specify the initial data.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Do you mean $u(t=0,x)$? I assumed it does not matter for the solution method what it is. You can make up an initial condition, e.g. $u(0,x) = 2$ if $x < 1$ and $u(0,x) = 1$ if $x>1$.

Comment: This question is also addressed here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72049/differential-equation-with-a-heavisidetheta-function-running-for-ever  --  your discontinuous diffusion coefficient is `1 + 2 HeavisideTheta[x - 1]`.

Comment: Membranes with 0 thickness do not exist and thus I'd say a model were the thickness is assumed to be 0 is the hack, not the one with a dimension.

Comment: @user21 In many cases it is orders of magnitude thinner though. But that is not really the main reason to treat it as infinitely thin. Usually, a physicist would want to understand (and as part of understanding, numerically solve) a simplified model. The goal is not to model a real system as accurately as possible (that's for engineers who work with systems where the physics is well understood already), but to understand the behaviour of a mathematical model. Our starting point is the equations. Giving it a thickness is a deviation from those, and in this sense, a hack.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I do not think it's a good idea to start to develop a simplified model if there is nothing to compare to. How do you know your simplified model is working when there is no understanding of  the physically realistic case. Concerning the aspect ration, start with something realistic. Then you can find a simplified model.

Comment: I'm afraid that's getting too deep into the philosophy of science (or physics) :-)

Comment: Probably right.

Comment: @user21 Anyway, putting aside what is the "right approach" philosophically, let me confirm that your opinion is that given the _current_ facilities available in Mathematica, giving the membrane a thickness is the best practical way forward?

Comment: @EricTowers I think you meant to post that on the other question, linked at the beginning of this post, right?

Comment: @Szabolcs, for anything beyond 1D, yes. Especially for complicated geometries. One might be able to work around this with some low level fem programming and program the interface condition yourself. I for one am not sure how to do it. IMHO Tim's approach is the only one that generalizes.

Comment: @Szabolcs Since you post 1D problem and accepted 2D solution, then may be you also interested in 3D solution for membrane published on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193789/how-to-apply-different-equations-to-different-parts-of-a-geometry-in-pde ?

Comment: Version 13 has [ToGradedMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToGradedMesh.html) and [ElementMeshRegionProduct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMeshRegionProduct.html).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This answer is a partial response to a comment about extending the approach to more complex geometry.  The preliminary results seemed encouraging so I thought I would share my workflow.

I think there are times where one might want to model the membrane region due to difficulties imposing internal boundary conditions.  For chemical interphase mass transfer, there can be discontinuities in both coefficients and also the field variable due to phase changes.  The characteristic length and timescales of interfacial phenomena are so small, that they are generally assumed to be in equilibrium leading to jumps in concentrations as shown in the following figures.

[image: Absorption]

[image: Membrane]

To use the FEM method it is good to cast your equations into coefficient form as shown [FEM Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1222366601).

$$\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {t^2}}}u + d\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u + \nabla \cdot\left( { - c\nabla u - \alpha u + \gamma } \right) + \beta \cdot\nabla u + au - f = 0$$

By doing so, we can use region IDs to toggle equations to be active in some regions and suppressed in others.

For interfacial chemical equilibria, we toggle a source term in the interface region that drives the phase concentrations to their equilibrium values.  I posted an article about [Modeling jump conditions in interphase mass transfer](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1551098) on the Wolfram Community.  In the end, the modeling a thin interface region compared favorably to commercial codes that had support for internal boundary conditions.

What I present here is an approach based on the [Acoustic Cloak Monograph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/ModelCollection/AcousticCloak.html#478938269) to provide an efficient quad mesh for the interface.

## Interface Modeling

Since the interface is a small feature, model sizes can grow to be very large if one tries to isotropically mesh the region.  The Acoustic Cloak Monograph, uses high aspect QuadElements to get around this problem.  I also make use of the Tensor Product Grid example in the [RegionProduct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionProduct.html?q=RegionProduct) documentation to create 2D regions.

## Helper Functions

I had some difficulty combining some multiple Tri regions with Quad regions so I hacked some functions together.  There is probably a better way to do this, but it seems to work.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(* From RegionProduct Documentation *)
pointsToMesh[data_] :=
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
(* Convert RegionProduct to ElementMesh *)
rp2Mesh[rh_, rv_, marker_] := Module[{sqr, crd, inc, msh, mrkrs},
  sqr = RegionProduct[rh, rv];
  crd = MeshCoordinates[sqr];
  inc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[sqr, 2];
  mrkrs = ConstantArray[marker, First@Dimensions@inc];
  msh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, 
    "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[inc, mrkrs]}]
  ]
(* Create an annular ElementMesh *)
annularMesh[r_, th_, rh_, rv_, marker_] := 
 Module[{r1, r2, th1, th2, anMesh, crd, melms, newcrd},
  {r1, r2} = r;
  {th1, th2} = th;
   anMesh = rp2Mesh[rh, rv, marker];
  crd = anMesh["Coordinates"];
  melms = anMesh["MeshElements"];
  newcrd = 
   Chop[{#1 Cos[#2], #1 Sin[#2]} & @@@ ({r1 + (r2 - r1) #1, 
         th1 + (th2 - th1) #2} & @@@ crd), 1*^-7];
  ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> newcrd, "MeshElements" -> melms]
  ]
(* Combine and Flatten 2 Tri Meshes *)
combineTriMeshes[mesh1_, mesh2_] := 
 Module[{crd1, crd2, newcrd, numinc1, inc, inc1, inc2, mrk, mrk1, 
   mrk2, elm1, elm2, melms, m},
  crd1 = mesh1["Coordinates"];
  crd2 = mesh2["Coordinates"];
  numinc1 = First@Dimensions@crd1;
  newcrd = crd1~Join~ crd2;
  inc1 =  ElementIncidents[mesh1["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  inc2 =  numinc1 + ElementIncidents[mesh2["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  mrk1 = ElementMarkers[mesh1["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  mrk2 = ElementMarkers[mesh2["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  melms = {TriangleElement[inc1~Join~inc2, mrk1~Join~mrk2]};
  m = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> newcrd, "MeshElements" -> melms];
  m
  ]
(* Combine and Flatten 2 Quad Meshes *)
combineQuadMeshes[mesh1_, mesh2_] := 
 Module[{crd1, crd2, newcrd, numinc1, inc, inc1, inc2, mrk, mrk1, 
   mrk2, elm1, elm2, melms, m},
  crd1 = mesh1["Coordinates"];
  crd2 = mesh2["Coordinates"];
  numinc1 = First@Dimensions@crd1;
  newcrd = crd1~Join~ crd2;
  inc1 =  ElementIncidents[mesh1["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  inc2 =  numinc1 + ElementIncidents[mesh2["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  mrk1 = ElementMarkers[mesh1["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  mrk2 = ElementMarkers[mesh2["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  melms = {QuadElement[inc1~Join~inc2, mrk1~Join~mrk2]};
  m = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> newcrd, "MeshElements" -> melms];
  m
  ]
(* Combine Mixed Quad and Tri Mesh *)
combineMeshes[mesh1_, mesh2_] := 
 Module[{crd1, crd2, newcrd, numinc1, inc1, inc2, mrk1, mrk2, elm1, 
   elm2, melms, m},
  crd1 = mesh1["Coordinates"];
  crd2 = mesh2["Coordinates"];
  numinc1 = First@Dimensions@crd1;
  newcrd = crd1~Join~ crd2;
  inc1 =  ElementIncidents[mesh1["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  inc2 =  ElementIncidents[mesh2["MeshElements"]][[1]];
  mrk1 = ElementMarkers[mesh1["MeshElements"]] // Flatten;
  mrk2 = ElementMarkers[mesh2["MeshElements"]] // Flatten;
  elm1 = mesh1["MeshElements"][[1, 0]];
  elm2 = mesh2["MeshElements"][[1, 0]];
  melms = Flatten@{elm1[inc1, mrk1], elm2[inc2 + Length[crd1], mrk2]};
  m = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> newcrd, "MeshElements" -> melms];
  m = MeshOrderAlteration[m, 2];
  m
  ]
```

## Build a Mixed Element Mesh

Here we will create a half symmetry model of an inner liquid drop, surrounded by a membrane (meshed with flat quads), and gas.

```
(* Define regions association for clearer assignment *)
regs = <|"inner" -> 10, "membrane" -> 20, "outer" -> 30|>;
(* Geometry Parameters *)
thick = rinner/100.;
rinner = 1.0;
router = rinner + thick;
rmax = 2 rinner;
theta = 180 Degree;
afrac = theta/(360 Degree);
(* Define Mesh Levels *)
nRadial = 10;
nAngular = 120;
(* Elements across the thickness of the membrane *)
rh = pointsToMesh[Subdivide[0, 1, nRadial]];
(* Angular resolution *)
rv = pointsToMesh[Subdivide[0, 1, nAngular afrac]];
(* Create Membrane Quad Mesh *)
membraneMesh = 
  annularMesh[{rinner, router}, {0 Degree, 180 Degree}, rh, rv, 
   regs["membrane"]];
membraneMesh[
 "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Orange]]
(* Create inner drop mesh based on membraneMesh *)
bmeshinner = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   Rectangle[{-rinner, 0}, {rinner, (rinner + router)/2}], 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> rinner/20];
coordinates = 
  Join[Select[membraneMesh["Coordinates"], Norm[#] <= rinner &], 
   Select[bmeshinner["Coordinates"], #[[2]] == 0 &]];
incidents = Partition[FindShortestTour[coordinates][[2]], 2, 1];
innerBoundary = 
  ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[incidents]}];
innerMesh = 
  ToElementMesh[innerBoundary, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01/4, "SteinerPoints" -> False, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{0, rinner/2}, regs["inner"]}];
innerMesh[
 "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Blue]]

(* Create outer drop mesh based on membraneMesh *)
bmeshouter = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[Rectangle[{-rmax, 0}, {rmax, rmax}], 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> rinner/20];
coordinates = 
  Join[Select[membraneMesh["Coordinates"], Norm[#] >= router &], 
   Select[bmeshouter["Coordinates"], #[[2]] == 0 &]];
coordinates = 
  Join[Select[membraneMesh["Coordinates"], Norm[#] >= router &], 
   Select[
    bmeshouter[
     "Coordinates"], (! ((-router <= #[[1]] <= router) && #[[2]] == 
          0)) &]];
incidents = Partition[FindShortestTour[coordinates][[2]], 2, 1];
outerBoundary = 
  ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[incidents]}];
outerMesh = 
  ToElementMesh[outerBoundary, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01/4, "SteinerPoints" -> False, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{0, (rmax + router)/2}, regs["outer"]}];
outerMesh[
 "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Green]]

(* Combine Meshes into one *)
mesh = combineTriMeshes[innerMesh, outerMesh];
mesh = combineMeshes[mesh, membraneMesh];
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (FaceForm[#] & /@ {Blue, Green, Orange})]]
mesh["Wireframe"[
  PlotRange -> {{-rmax/1.75, -router + 0.25}, {0, 0.25}}, 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (FaceForm[#] & /@ {Blue, Green, Orange})]]
```

[image: Boundary Meshes]

[image: Element Meshes]

## Set up and Solve Three Region PDE

After creating a 2D mesh, we set up our system of PDEs for gas and liquid concentrations.  Note that we introduce small diffusion coefficient, $dsmall$, to prevent species from leaking past the membrane.

For simplicity, we will initialize the system at zero concentration and use a Dirichlet condition of 1 for gas concentration on the left wall.

```
(* Inner Region *)
d1 = 0.1;
(* Outer Region *)
d2 = 3 d1;
(* Membrane Region *)
d3 = 10 d2;
dsmall = d1/10000;
(* Region Dependent Parameters *)
(* Diffusion Coeffiecients *)
di =  With[{d1 = d1, d2 = d2, d3 = d3, dsmall = dsmall}, 
   Piecewise[{{DiagonalMatrix@{d1, d1}, 
      ElementMarker == 
       regs["inner"]}, {DiagonalMatrix@{dsmall, dsmall}, 
      ElementMarker == regs["outer"]}, {DiagonalMatrix@{d3, d3}, 
      True}}]];
do =  With[{d1 = d1, d2 = d2, d3 = d3, dsmall = dsmall}, 
   Piecewise[{{DiagonalMatrix@{dsmall, dsmall}, 
      ElementMarker == regs["inner"]}, {DiagonalMatrix@{d2, d2}, 
      ElementMarker == regs["outer"]}, {DiagonalMatrix@{d3, d3}, 
      True}}]];
(* Toggle Source Terms for Interface *)
kappa = 1;
omega = Evaluate[If[ElementMarker == regs["membrane"], kappa, 0]];
kequil = 0.5;
c0 = 1;
tmax = 30;

dcli = DirichletCondition[ui[t, x, y] == 0, x == -rmax];
dcri = DirichletCondition[ui[t, x, y] == 0, x == rmax];
dclo = DirichletCondition[uo[t, x, y] == c0, x == -rmax];
dcro = DirichletCondition[uo[t, x, y] == 0, x == rmax];
ics = {ui[0, x, y] == 0, uo[0, x, y] == 0};
eqni =  D[ui[t, x, y], t] + 
    Inactive[Div][-di.Inactive[Grad][ui[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
    omega (kequil ui[t, x, y] - uo[t, x, y]) == 0;
eqno = D[uo[t, x, y], t] + 
    Inactive[Div][-do.Inactive[Grad][uo[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
    omega (kequil ui[t, x, y] - uo[t, x, y]) == 0;
pdes = {eqni, eqno};
uif = NDSolveValue[
   pdes~Join~{dcli, dcri, dclo, dcro}~Join~ics, {ui, uo}, {t, 0, 
    tmax}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
pltfn[u_, t_] := 
 Module[{plti, pltinf, plto}, 
  plti = ContourPlot[u[[1]][t, x, y], Element[{x, y}, innerMesh], 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> All, PlotRange -> {0, c0},
     ColorFunction -> "DarkBands"];
  pltinf = 
   ContourPlot[u[[1]][t, x, y], Element[{x, y}, membraneMesh], 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> All, PlotRange -> {0, c0},
     ColorFunction -> "DarkBands"];
  plto = ContourPlot[u[[2]][t, x, y], Element[{x, y}, outerMesh], 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> All, PlotRange -> {0, c0},
     ColorFunction -> "DarkBands"];
  Show[plto, pltinf, plti]]
```

[image: 2D Diffusion]

Comment: This looks like a very promising approach! Well done Tim.

Comment: I did ask not to do this, but you convinced me, so accepting this one ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for the accept!  I was not expecting it.  I know that you wanted a membrane free answer, but I thought this was worth sharing versus gathering dust on my hard drive.  FEM has its limitations, but it can be very flexible and efficient if you can work within those limitations.

Comment: @user21 Thank you very much!  I think it is a good start.  Maybe it would be a useful addition to have a region marker preserving  ElementMeshJoin to join compatible element types in FEMAddOns?

Comment: This suggestion has been made before - at that time I was hesitant because it very easy to generate faulty meshes with something like this. On the other hand there are certainly cases were such a functionality would make things much easier. Even in the Acoustic Cloak example would benefit from something like that.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Tim made a proposal to add anisotropic meshing capabilities to the FEM mesh generation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240408/18437). If you think this is worthwhile, consider giving this proposal an upvote

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution using [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) to discretize the system in $x$ direction. The condition at $x=1$ is then straightforwardly introduced in this approach:

```
{lb = 0, mb = 1, rb = 2, dl = 1, dmem = 2, dr = 3, tmax = 5};
    
With[{u = u[t, x]}, eq = D[u, t] == # D[D[u, x], x] & /@ {dl, dr};
  ic = {u == 2, u == 1} /. t -> 0;
  {bcl, bcr} = {{u == 2 /. x -> lb, dl D[u, x] /. x -> mb},
                {dr D[u, x] /. x -> mb, u == 1 /. x -> rb }}] ;

points = 25; {gridl, gridr} = Array[# &, points, #] & /@ {{lb, mb}, {mb, rb}};
difforder = 2;

{ptoofuncl, ptoofuncr} = pdetoode[u[t, x], t, #, difforder] & /@ {gridl, gridr};

del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
{odel, oder} = MapThread[del@#@#2 &, {{ptoofuncl, ptoofuncr}, eq}];
{odeicl, odeicr} = MapThread[#@#2 &, {{ptoofuncl, ptoofuncr}, ic}];
{odebcl, odebcr} = MapThread[#@#2 &, {{ptoofuncl, ptoofuncr}, {bcl, bcr}}];

linkterm = dmem (ur[1][t] - ul[1][t]);
rulel = u[1] -> ul[1];
ruler = u[1] -> ur[1];
odebcm = {linkterm == odebcl[[2]] /. rulel, linkterm == odebcr[[1]] /. ruler};

odebc = With[{sf = 1}, diffbc[t, sf]@{odebcl[[1]], odebcr[[2]], odebcm}];

sollst = NDSolveValue[{{odel, odeicl} /. rulel, {oder, odeicr} /. ruler, 
     odebc}, {u /@ gridl // Most, u /@ gridr // Rest, ul[1], ur[1]}, {t, 0, 
     tmax}]; // AbsoluteTiming

soll = rebuild[Join[sollst[[1]], {sollst[[3]]}], gridl]   
solr = rebuild[Join[{sollst[[4]]}, sollst[[2]]], gridr]    
sol = {t, x} \[Function] Piecewise[{{soll[t, x], x < mb}}, solr[t, x]]

Manipulate[Plot[sol[t, x], {x, lb, rb}], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my answer, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want to improve my answer if possible.

Answer (score 9):

We can use `NDSolve` with FEM by changing the variable `x->2-x` at `x>=1` and defining two equations on the same interval `(x,0,1)`, connected for `x = 1`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; d1 = 1; d2 = 3; dm = 1; reg = 
 ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1, {x}];
eq = {-d1 Laplacian[u1[t, x], {x}] + 
    D[u1[t, x], t], -d2 Laplacian[u2[t, x], {x}] + D[u2[t, x], t]};
ic = {u1[0, x] == 2, u2[0, x] == 1};
bc1 = NeumannValue[-dm (u1[t, x] - u2[t, x]), x == 1];
bc2 = NeumannValue[-dm (u2[t, x] - u1[t, x]), x == 1];
bc = DirichletCondition[{u1[t, x] == 2, u2[t, x] == 1}, x == 0];

{U1, U2} = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq[[1]] == bc1, eq[[2]] == bc2, bc, ic}, {u1, u2}, 
  x \[Element] reg, {t, 0, 2}]
```

Visualisation

```
Plot3D[{U1[t, x], U2[t, 2 - x]}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

If the membrane set in an arbitrary point `p`, then the code should be modified as follows:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; d1 = 1; d2 = 3; dm = 1; reg = 
     ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1, {x}]; p = 1.2; x1 = 
     x/p; x2 = (2 - x)/(2 - p); k1 = D[x1, x]; k2 = D[x2, x];
    eq = {-d1 k1^2 Laplacian[u1[t, x], {x}] + 
        D[u1[t, x], t], -d2 k2^2 Laplacian[u2[t, x], {x}] + 
        D[u2[t, x], t]};
    ic = {u1[0, x] == 2, u2[0, x] == 1};
    bc1 = NeumannValue[-dm k1 (u1[t, x] - u2[t, x]), x == 1];
    bc2 = NeumannValue[dm k2 (u2[t, x] - u1[t, x]), x == 1];
    bc = DirichletCondition[{u1[t, x] == 2, u2[t, x] == 1}, x == 0];
{U1, U2} = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq[[1]] == bc1, eq[[2]] == bc2, bc, ic}, {u1, u2}, 
  x \[Element] reg, {t, 0, 2}]
```

Visualisation

```
{Table[Plot[{U1[t, x1], U2[t, x2]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, 0, 2, .5}],   
Plot3D[{U1[t, x1], U2[t, x2]}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I came up with something similar before, but this technique doesn't really generalize for other domain shapes. What if the membrane is at x=0.5, not at x=1? I guess one domain can be artificially compressed to make it the same size as the other, and the equations re-scaled accordinagly. But what if we are in 2D and the membrane is circular?

Comment: @Szabolcs There is no general solution for this problem. If you interested in 2D or 3D solution then we could try to make code. But my answer is only for this special 1D case you posted above.

Comment: For now, I will ask for one generalization only: to put the membrane at an arbitrary position along $[0,2]$ instead of right in the middle. Anything beyond that should go in a separate question.

Comment: @Szabolcs You may want to try [`DChange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871).

Comment: @Szabolcs See update to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Version 12.1.1 has a new PDE modeling tutorial on [Modeling Mass Transport](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/MassTransport/MassTransport.html). The section [Interphase Mass Transfer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/MassTransport/MassTransport.html#509267359) shows an example of how inter phase mass transport can be modeled with `NDSolve`. The related question of modeling phase change is shown in the section [Transient PDEs with Nonlinear Transient Coefficients](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#353016153) of the [Finite Element Programming tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html)

*Update:*
There is also a section on modeling Phase Change in the Heat Transfer tutorial PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer#135129751 or online [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#135129751)